# Dynamic find conditions in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an index action in rails that can handle quite a few params eg:

```
params[:first_name] # can be nil or first_name
params[:age]        # can be nil or age 
params[:country]    # can be nil or country
```

When finding users I would like to AND all the conditions that are not nil. This gives me 8 permutations of the find conditions.

How can I can I keep my code DRY and flexible and not end up with a bunch of `if` statements just to build the conditions for the find. Keep in mind that if no conditions are specified I just want to return `User.all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work quite nicely:

```
conditions = params.slice(:first_name, :age, :country)
hash = conditions.empty? ? {} : {:conditions => conditions}
@users = User.all hash
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
conditions = params.only(:first_name, :age, :country)
conditions = conditions.delete_if {|key, value| value.blank?}

if conditions.empty?
  User.all
else
  User.all(:conditions => conditions)
end
```

Comment: Oddly enough my params hash does not seem to have an only method

Answer (score 3):

I would normally use named scopes for something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :name_like, lambda {|name| {:conditions => ["first_name LIKE ?", "#{name}%"]}}
  named_scope :age, lambda {|age| {:conditions => {:age => age}}}
  named_scope :in_country, lambda {|country| {:conditions => {:country => country}}}
end

class UsersController < ActionController
  def index
    root = User
    root = root.name_like(params[:first_name]) unless params[:first_name].blank?
    root = root.age(params[:age]) unless params[:age].blank?
    root = root.country(params[:country]) unless params[:age].blank?

    @users = root.paginate(params[:page], :order => "first_name")
  end
end
```

That's what I normally do.

Answer (score 1):

Using James Healy answer, I modify the code to be used in Rails 3.2 (in case anyone out there need this).

```
conditions = params.slice(:first_name, :age, :country)
conditions = conditions.delete_if {|key, value| value.blank?}

@users = User.where(conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Ambition](http://github.com/defunkt/ambition/tree/master), or a number of other ActiveRecord extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me too

```
conditions = params[:search] ? params[:search].keep_if{|key, value| !value.blank?} : {}
User.all(:conditions => conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be on an ancient project (Rails 2.x) and very messy, you could do something like the following for adding new fields to the original query.

Original code:

```
User.find(:all,
   :conditions => ['first_name LIKE ? AND age=? AND country=?',
        "#{name}%", age, country]
```

Adding a new dynamic condition on `zip_code` field:

```
zip_code  = params[:zip_code]   # Can be blank
zip_query = "AND zip_code = ?" unless zip_code.blank?

User.find(:all,
   :conditions => ['first_name LIKE ? AND age=? AND country=? #{zip_query}',
        "#{name}%", age, country, zip_code].reject(&:blank?)
```

Adding a `reject(&:blank?)` to the `conditions` arrays will filter the `nil` value.

**Note:** The other answers are much better if you are coding from zero, or refactoring.